# Display pygame unit tests

Tags: python, unit-testing, pygame

I have created a game using Python 3.6 + Pygame though any tests I have made will not display. I was wondering how I would display the tests when ran or output the tests to a file. This is the code I currently have (my game is called CatchTheFruit.py):

```
import CatchTheFruit
import unittest

class IntegerArithmentic(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_checkWorks(self):
        self.assertEqual((1 + 2), 3)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

This is not one of the tests i will use though it should still display nonetheless. When this is ran it will launch my game but display no tests? So how would I make it so the tests can be viewed? Would this be due to an issue in the code for my game or would the tests need to be modified?

Comment: Have you already tried this script from a shell ? sometimes the structure of the project doesn't fit, you may need to move some files or write another way to import modules

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, unittest is displayed in the shell/console, your test runs OK:

```
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
```

The purpose of unit tests is not to be displayed to the player, so the better solution would be to log the results to a file.

`unittest.main()` accepts a parameter as a stream (called `testRunner`), you can use it with something like this to produce a file in the same folder:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    with open('test.log', 'w') as f:
        trunner = unittest.TextTestRunner(f)
        unittest.main(testRunner=trunner)
```

(then you could still use this file as a source to show the results on the pygame screen)

**EDIT :**

To answer the issue happening when you import your game module:

A module is read and evaluated when you import it, so if you declare a variable that launch the game, like `game = launch_game()`, the function will be called.

Easy test: create a first file :

```
#mygame.py

def main():
    print('this is printed when module is imported')

game = main()
```

Then in another one, perform the import:

```
# test.py

import mygame

print('This one goes next')
```

When you execute the test.py, it will display the two print statements.

So you'll need to encapsulate the variable game in a structure like :

```
def main():
    print('this one is not printed')

if __name__ == '__main__':

    game = main()
```

Comment: This almost works for me, it will display all errors and things in the file so that works great. 
`import CatchTheFruit`
But for some reason when i import my game that uses pygame, it is opening the game but will not display any tests at all, not even in the file?

Comment: i edited the post to explain (maybe) why it's launching the game when you import it,  but now i'm not sure about what you really want to do with these unit tests, you need to perform them everytime you launch the game ?